# Refresh Modal AJAX content dynamic from DB and with PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I want to refresh my Modal div every 1 sec from the database.
It should refresh it without closing the actual Modal and a interval from one second
My modal Content:

```
<div id="view-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">

                                <h4 class="modal-title">Test</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">

                                <div id="dynamic-content"></div>

                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('click', '#test', function(e){

          e.preventDefault();

          var uid = $(this).data('id');

          $('#dynamic-content').html('');



            $.ajax({
              url: 'test.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: 'id='+uid,
              dataType: 'html'
            })

            .done(function(data){
              console.log(data);  
              $('#dynamic-content').html('');    
              $('#dynamic-content').html(data);

            })




        });

      });
```

The Button:

```
<button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$data['id'].'" data-target="#view-modal">Test</button>
```

I want to refresh this part here:

```
 $.ajax({
              url: 'test.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: 'id='+uid,
              dataType: 'html'
            })

            .done(function(data){
              console.log(data);  
              $('#dynamic-content').html('');    
              $('#dynamic-content').html(data);

            })
```

every 1 second without closing the actual modal or reloading the site it should just refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Put your AJAX in a function:

```
function ajaxFunction (uid){
 $.ajax({
     url: 'test.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {id:uid},
     dataType: 'html',
     success:function(data){
          console.log(data);  
          $('#dynamic-content').html('');    
          $('#dynamic-content').html(data);
    }     
});


}
```

The set an interval for 1 second:

```
setInterval(ajaxFunction(uid), 1000);
```

**EDIT:**
Full code here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#test', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var uid = $(this).data('id');
      $('#dynamic-content').html('');
    });
  setInterval(ajaxFunction(uid), 1000);
  });

function ajaxFunction (uid){
 $.ajax({
     url: 'test.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {id:uid},
     dataType: 'html',
     success:function(data){
          console.log(data);  
          $('#dynamic-content').html('');    
          $('#dynamic-content').html(data);
    }     
});        
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Have you got any errors in the console log?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't even looked at your Ajax properly.. when using `POST` as the method, your data should be an object `{name:value}` see my edit for the correction

Comment: Add a `console.log('in function');` line in the Ajax function before the Ajax itself and open up the console and see if that gets printed every second

Comment: The uid is not getting passed into the function if i do setInterval at the end of $(document).ready(function(){ ..

Comment: Put it back in the click function then but keep the console log and see what you get

Comment: Then its only calling the function 1 time .. and not every 1 sec